# fetch data from nested JSON object in a single line

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This is my JSON data ....

```
{"comp1":["$.Create_Keypair1_Keypair_name"]}
```

I want to get the value "Create_Keypair1_Keypair_name".but all the keys and values are dynamic.but the object always have single data.
I have Object.keys(temp).It shows only ["comp1"]  i need 
`$.Create_Keypair1_Keypair_name` only....

Comment: `var key = Object.keys(temp)[0]; var value = temp[key];`

Comment: Can you provide an example of your data?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var data = {"comp1":["$.Create_Keypair1_Keypair_name"]}
for (var key in data) {
   console.log(data[key])
}
```

This will log `$.Create_Keypair1_Keypair_name`.

Answer (score 0):

From what I am understanding each object will have a single value. If the is the case then you do not need the array in the object. You can do this.

```
 var tempy = {"comp":"ksmdfnsfdnsdfn"}
```

Then do this to ge the value.

```
tempy.comp
```

Or if you need the keys.

```
Object.keys(tempy)
```

Answer (score 0):

you might be looking for this

```
var temp = {"comp1":["$.Create_Keypair1_Keypair_name"]}
Object.keys(temp).forEach(function(key){
    console.log(temp[key]);
});
```